# GCC exports decorated function name only from dll

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, stdcall, name-decoration

I have a dll, it exports a function...

```
extern "C"
int __stdcall
MP_GetFactory( gmpi::IMpUnknown** returnInterface )
{
}
```

I compile this with Code::Blocks GCC compiler (V3.4.5). Problem: resulting dll exports decorated function name...

```
MP_GetFactory@4
```

This fails to load, should be plain old...

```
MP_GetFactory
```

I've researched this for about 4 hours. I think --add-stdcall-alias is the option to fix this. My Code::Blocks log shows...

> mingw32-g++.exe -shared  -Wl,--out-implib=bin\Debug\libGainGCC.a -Wl,--dll  obj\Debug\se_sdk3\mp_sdk_audio.o obj\Debug\se_sdk3\mp_sdk_common.o obj\Debug\Gain\Gain.o  obj\Debug\Gain\gain.res  -o bin\Debug\GainGCC.sem --add-stdcall-alias  -luser32

..so I think that's the correct option in there? But no luck. Dependancy Walker show only the decorated name being exported.
I got It to kinda work by using __cdecl instead of __stdcall, the name is then exported ok, but the function corrupts the stack when called (because the caller expected the other calling convention).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, finally figured it out.

Project/Build Options/Linker/Other Linker Options
-Wl,--kill-at

...kills the decoration '@' symbol etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias and the "kill-at" tricks will make the generated import library file not usable.